# How come these divs are not lining up?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble formatting these divs.... I put a border around my divs so you can see what is going on... I am trying to line these up like the second image, and I do not see why my top div isnt exactly right, I want it to be able to expand all the way over until it hits the profile photo div, but it cannot be any taller than it currently is. I want the actual message to be able to fit anywhere that is not the profile picture or the name plate. I do not understand why the chat is intersecting the nameplate.

If I am unclear, the top picture is what it is doing, and the second picture is what I am trying to accomplish

Here is what it is doing...

[image]

I need it to do this

[image]

```
.chat{
border: 2px solid #73AD21;  
font-weight:100;
color:#ffffff;
letter-spacing:0pt;
word-spacing:1pt;
font-size:300%;
text-align:right;
font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica Ultra Light, Helvetica Light, Helvetica, Roboto, Lucida Grande, Tahoma, comic sans, comic sans ms, cursive, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
line-height:1;
margin: 20px;
padding:0px;
opacity:1.0;
position: relative
}
.newChat{


}
.chatBubble{
    position: relative;
    left:40px;

max-width: 400px;
max-height: 350px;
padding: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
/*
border-radius: 10px;
border-spacing: 10px 50px;
border: #7F7F7F solid 4px;
*/
word-wrap: break-word;
height: -webkit-fit-content;
height: -moz-fit-content;
width: -webkit-fit-content;
width: -moz-fit-content;
float: bottom;
}
.speechBubble{
    max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;

}

html, body, .glass {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.glass::before {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    content: ' ';
    opacity: 0.4;
}

/*

*/
.glass {
    /*
border-radius: 10px;
border-spacing: 10px 50px;
border: #7F7F7F solid 4px;
*/
    background: rgba(81, 81, 81, .3);
        position: relative;
    left:40px;
    bottom:0px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 75px;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;   
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* height: -webkit-fit-content; */
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    float: bottom;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.profilePic{
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    /* border-radius: 5px; */



var thisBubble = $('<div>').addClass('glass').append(
                $('<div>').addClass('nameTag').append(fullName)).append(
                $('<img src="'+ profilePic +'">').addClass('profilePic')).append(               
                $('<div>').addClass('chat').append(message)).appendTo('#MenuBackground');
     setTimeout(function(){thisBubble.fadeOut('slow');}, 10000);
    }   
}
.nameTag{
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    font-weight:100;
color:#ffffff;
letter-spacing:0pt;
word-spacing:1pt;
font-size:100%;
text-align:right;
font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica Ultra Light, Helvetica Light, Helvetica, Roboto, Lucida Grande, Tahoma, comic sans, comic sans ms, cursive, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: 5px;
    float: top; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ladijo/1/edit?html,css,output)
You can easily implement it with flexbox.
structure your html like

```
<div class='profile'>

    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="body">
      <header>Lorem Ipsum</header>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim aperiam veniam odit in, maxime..</article>
    </div>

</div>
```

then in your css

```
.profile{
  display: flex;
}

.profile .body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.profile .body>article{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by making separate div for text, and then apply display:inline-block; for both

You could also try to set position:absoulte for text, then all you need is adjust margins.(but depends of the use)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="" class="pic" style="float:left;background:yellow;width:300px;">

      <div class="overlay" style="float:left;width:30%;height:200px;">
      Profile Picture
      <img src=""/></div>
      <div id="right-side" style="float:left;width:70%;">
      <div id="RightPicAbove" class="info" style="background:red;height:20px;">
        Name plate
      </div>
      <div id="RightPicBelow" class="info" style="background:green;height:180px;">
        Chat goes here..
      </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```